# .htaccess RewriteRule is changing URL in address bar when I won't want it to

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Okay first of all, I want to make my URLs prettier using .htaccess, and I've never done this before. (I'm developing a website on my local machine and viewing the pages with EasyPHP 12.1)

If I type in
**/localhost/me/about/** I want it to serve the contents of
**/localhost/me/about.php** WITHOUT changing the URL in the address bar.

If I type in
**/localhost/me/about.php** I want it to serve up the contents of that file, then CHANGE the address bar to read
**/localhost/me/about/**

Here's my entire .htaccess file so far, and yes it's in the root of my directory, the same directory with all of the .php files:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://localhost/me/$1.php
```

This successfully redirects from **localhost/me/about/** to **localhost/me/about.php** (and it works for all of my other pages too). The thing is, I DO NOT want the URL to change in the address bar. Everywhere I look online, I see that I'm supposed to add the [R] flag at the end of my third line if I DO want the address bar updated. I don't have the flag, but the URL in the address bar still changing. What am I missing? Is there a flag I can add to force it not to change?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `[L]` flag at the end of third line. The link will be internally forwarded so you can keep your `localhost/me/about/` in the address bar.

Comment: It's not working for me... I'm not sure what other information I can provide. The URL keeps changing in the address bar even with the `[L]` flag.

Comment: I think so... I can get it to require a username and password, and I can get it to redirect like I mentioned in the OP. I just wish the URL didn't get changed in the address bar. Is it possible for some of it to work and some of it not to?

Comment: Make sure your sever has mod_rewrite installed and active. Also in your apache configuration file AllowOverride Directive should configured to allow .htaccess file.

Comment: I followed the [EasyPHP instructions](http://www.easyphp.org/faq.php#0) and those changes were already made.